# jpa query with case condition in criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have one mysql query like below where I'm using conditional parameter in where clause. How can I rewrite the same in JPA?

SELECT * FROM  notification n where if (n.feature_details_id=16, category_id IN (SELECT r.id FROM procurement_category r where r.spendpool_id IN (SELECT spendpool_id FROM procurement_category p where p.id IN (1,4))),category_id IN (4)) and (recipient =76 or n.recipient_type = 'ALL' and n.id NOT IN (select ns.notification_id from notification_statistics ns where ns.user_id =76 and ns.status = 'DISMISSED') and n.sender != 76);

I've tried this. It only works when passing single value to param categoryIds.

```
@Query("select n from Notification n "
        + "where (n.category.id IN(case when n.featureDetails.id=2 then(SELECT r.id FROM ProcurementCategory r where r.spendpoolId.id IN "
        + "(SELECT p.spendpoolId.id FROM ProcurementCategory p where p.id IN (:categoryIds))) "
        + "else (:categoryIds) end )) "
        + "and n.recipient =:recipient "
        + "or n.recipientType = 'ALL' "
        + "and n.category.id IN (SELECT r.id FROM ProcurementCategory r where r.spendpoolId.id IN "
        + "(SELECT p.spendpoolId.id FROM ProcurementCategory p where p.id IN (:categoryIds))) "
        + "and n.id NOT IN (select ns.notification.id from NotificationStatistics ns where ns.user.id =:recipient and ns.status = 'DISMISSED') "
        + "and n.sender != :recipient " )
```

If passing multiple values it gives error like

05-11-2016 09:58:32.153 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
05-11-2016 09:58:32.154 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG c.b.i.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.beroe.insync2.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.dataIntegrityViolationException() with argument[s]

Comment: JPQL has CASE expressions http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#case  hence you should be able to try something

Comment: @Neil - I have already used case condition as supports in JPA. As put above the query works when I pass single value in categoryIds, If I pass list of values its gives error like "Operand should contain 1 column"